# Creating a Modal Form mahapps WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a question about a bookstore called [Mahapps](http://mahapps.com/)

Currently I'm using and I think it's great, I have a menu and options position in a frame. Now in some forms I open a new window but that does not look good, then I want to open a modal window (as well as done in webapps).

You can create a modal window Mahapps ??? to take a UserControl and display it in a modal ??

Comment: [Dialogs](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html)

Comment: Hi Chris, I mean it is a modal window where you can put a form, the dialog only lets me use that are predefined (that I understand).

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, I did not check the whole doc, here's one of the more detailed example tutorials for [inspiration](http://www.global-webnet.net/IDontKnowAnyBetter/post/2015/11/20/mahapps-custom-dialog-mvvm-light-and-me)

Comment: That's just what I need, but just found this link that is the same developer mahapps apparently would serve me, you know ?? It is stable? [link](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new window and show it when you need it. You can do this like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    private void InitLogin()
    {
        using (var lw = new LoginWindow())
        {
            this.Hide();
            lw.ShowDialog();
            if (lw.Status == Status.Success)
            {
                loginDone = true;
                this.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

public partial class LoginWindow : MetroWindow, IDisposable
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    // ... 
}
```

here LoginWindow() is your "modal" window and this points to the main window

Comment: Hi Catalintry as you indicate, but the window is not so raises error IDisposable

Comment: You have to implement IDisposable the easy way to do this:  public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Close();
        }

Comment: Or I didn't understand your problem (about the error) correctly?

Comment: In the window throws me an error "does not implement the IDisposable interface member", and In the window throws me an error "does not implement the IDisposable interface member"
and where I invoke the modal window says "must be able to implicitly become IDisposable"

Comment: just found this link that is the same developer mahapps apparently would serve me, you know ?? It is stable? [link](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow)

Comment: I have never used this link that you shared with me. The only time I have done something similar I have used this solution that I have described to you. But you can try that lib (never hurts :)  to try new thinks) . The errror that are you getting is because you haven't implemented the IDisposable interface.

Comment: I do not seem to understand that I do :(

Comment: just add this method `public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Close();
        }`   to your modal window - in this example in the LoginWindow class and this should solve your error about IDisposable.

Comment: now he says it does not contain a definition for close.

Comment: Be aware that LoginWindow it also inherits from MetroWindow that code `this.Close()` is from the Base Window of WPF. so it should be there.

Comment: and I think I know why! Will because what use is a "UserControl" ??

I have a User Control pq have a master where I open the UserControl within a "Frame", but now here I show this UserControl on a Modal.

Comment: I am not completely sure that I undestand what are you doing but if you are using a UserControl you can try `Window.GetWindow(this).Close();`

Comment: I did as I indicas, and it works but I can not access ShowDialog does not exist.
`using (var modal = new RegistroEquipo())
            {
                this.Hide();
                modal.sh
            }`

Comment: ShowDialog is only available for a window, so because you are using a UserControl a possible solution would be to replace ShowDialog with this `Window window = new Window 
    {
        Title = "My User Control Dialog",
        Content = new RegistroEquipo()
    };
    window.ShowDialog(); `

Comment: Many Thanks, works perfectly as I !!!! This is the code.

`private void loginBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){Window window = new Window{Content = new RegistroEquipo(),Width = 550,Height = 480,WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,Owner = this};AplicarEfecto(this);window.ShowDialog();}

private void AplicarEfecto(Window win){var objBlur = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect {Radius = 5};win.Effect = objBlur;}`